# Moving Rows Between MySQL Servers

Tags: mysql

I have two physical MySQL servers running on a network (ServerA & ServerB). ServerA is populating TableA with rows. I'd like to constantly move these rows to ServerB TableB over the network. When the rows have been moved to TableB, I'd like them removed from TableA. When this operation is complete, I'd like it to happen all over again.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: 1) write code 2) run code 3) test code 4) debug code. we help with #4. #1-3 are entirely your responsibility.

Comment: Part of the process, I would think: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html